# How to track process forked by bash script?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, kubectl, fork-join

Not pure bash question, but requires a combo knowledge of bash and kubernetes cli to fully answer. I want to do some port forwarding thing with kubernetes alongside with other job (like telepresense), and my bash script doing like that:

```
# Killing all kubectl port forwards that might remain after previous launch.
kill $(pidof kubectl)
#run kube-proxy to tunnel port 2828 to the my pod on k8s
kubectl port-forward deployment/my 2828:2828 -n myns  & 
#wait for proxy to establish
sleep 10
```

this script has downsides

- killing all kubectl, not only mine
- does not kill kubectl at the end of script (could it just handle ctrl+c and "join" process gracefully instead of killing it)?
- may sleep longer than needed (can i track if kubectl server is established and script can continue?)
- kubectl error is not handled (should exit if error happened)

how could I solve mentioned drawbacks?

Answer (score 1):

You should track the pid of the created `kubectl` process and possible store it in a "lock" file.

Something like: `pid=$!` and `echo $! > lockfile`

Then in the beginning of the script you could check that lockfile and and kill the process:

```
pid=$(<lockfile)
kill "$pid"
kubectl port-forward deployment/my 2828:2828 -n myns  & 
pid=$!
echo "$pid" > lockfile
```

This way you can also check to see if the process is already running or it have stopped:

```
pid=$(<lockfile)
if ps "$pid" 2>&1 >/dev/null
then
  echo "Already running, no need to restart"
  exit 0
fi
kubectl port-forward deployment/my 2828:2828 -n myns  & 
pid=$!
echo "$pid" > lockfile
```

This will however not work if `kubectl` forks and stops the parent process.

Comment: i guess `$!` is a pid, and `$?` is a error code

Comment: @xakepp35 you are correct. If only someone had decided to use informative parameter names, so that one didn't have to test these out from time to time.